Where's NetworkManager in ubuntu 24.04?
The NetworkManager service is absent from my ubuntu server 24.04. I still get internet connections, but I can't manage them through systemd like before.
Is it really a bug, or is it by design, in which case I guess manually installing network-manager could be a problem?
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"

$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.


https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-declarative-approach-to-linux-networking-with-netplan  https://ubuntu.com/blog/netplan-configuration-across-desktop-server-cloud-and-iot   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server uses Netplan just as the prior release of Ubuntu 23.10 Server used.. NetworkManager was used by Desktop systems more recently though  (are you new to Server systems? though adding desktops to server system would have added NM)  https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-bionic-netplan etc

Yes, I'm indeed new to the server systems. I'll go have a look at netplan and ubuntu servers in general. Thanks for the answer!

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server uses Netplan just as the prior release of Ubuntu 23.10 Server used.
Links that maybe useful:

https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-declarative-approach-to-linux-networking-with-netplan
https://ubuntu.com/blog/netplan-configuration-across-desktop-server-cloud-and-iot
https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-bionic-netplan


Netplan replaced ifupdown as the default configuration utility starting with Ubuntu 17.10 Artful [Server].

NetworkManager was used by Desktop systems more recently though, and note adding a desktop to a server install can add NetworkManager (NM) to a Server install.

They are split into Wi-Fi & Network inside the Settings:
Wi-Fi:

Network:

